# PyTorch high-dimensional tensor through linear layer

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor of size (32, 128, 50) in PyTorch. These are 50-dim word embeddings with a batch size of 32. That is, the three indices in my size correspond to number of batches, maximum sequence length (with 'pad' token), and the size of each embedding. Now, I want to pass this through a linear layer to get an output of size (32, 128, 1). That is, for every word embedding in every sequence, I want to make it one dimensional. I tried adding a linear layer to my network going from 50 to 1 dimension, and my output tensor is of the desired shape. So I think this works, but I would like to understand how PyTorch deals with this issue, since I did not explicitly tell it which dimension to apply the linear layer to. I played around with this and found that:

- If I input a tensor of shape (32, 50, 50) -- thus creating ambiguity by having two dimensions along which the linear layer could be applied to (two 50s) -- it only applies it to the last dim and gives an output tensor of shape (32, 50, 1).
- If I input a tensor of shape (32, 50, 128) it does NOT output a tensor of shape (32, 1, 128), but rather gives me an error.

This suggests that a linear layer in PyTorch applies the transformation to the last dimension of your tensor. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `nn.Linear` [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), it is specified that the input of this module can be any tensor of size `(*, H_in)` and the output will be a tensor of size `(*, H_out)`, where:

1. `*` means any number of dimensions
2. `H_in` is the number of `in_features`
3. `H_out` is the number of `out_features`

To understand this better, for a `tensor` of size `(n, m, 50)` can be processed by a `Linear` module with `in_features=50`, while a `tensor` of size `(n, 50, m)` can be processed by a `Linear` module with `in_features=m` (in your case `128`).